# Google Maps: How to change Marker default red color and add label

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, markers

I think this should be rather easy at first. However It takes me many hours searching on the Internet without getting a solution.

I can add a Marker on a Google Map with Label, as below:

```
// Adding a marker to the map 
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.48, 114.20),
    map: map,
    title: 'My House',
    label: {
        text: 'A',
        color: '#79E149'
    }
});
```

The default color is red.

My question:
How can I change the Red color of Marker to other color, for example, Green?

I noticed that most answers suggest to use an external icon, for example:

```
// Adding a marker to the map 
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.48, 114.20),
    map: map,
    title: 'My House',
    **icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',**
    label: {
        text: 'A',
        color: '#79E149'
    }
});
```

However:
1. The label will not appear when use this kind of icons.

2. Actually I don't want to use external image as the URL may be changed later. In fact many icons seems disappear already, for example:
   http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/blank.png

Thanks and best regards

Alex

Comment: Your [sample code shows a label for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/oeze66c5/2/), it is just green so hard to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your label text is green (#79E149) so it blends in with the marker
2. You probably don't want a "dot" on the marker if you want to put a label on it (change the marker icon's name to "green" from "green-dot").
3. The [LabelOrigin](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) of the icon is wrong for that particular marker/label combination

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/oeze66c5/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.48, 114.20),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  // Adding a marker to the map 
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.48, 114.20),
    map: map,
    title: 'My House',
    icon: {
      url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png',
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15, 10)
    },
    label: {
      text: 'A',
      color: 'black'
    }
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.49194, 114.204426),
    map: map,
    title: 'My Other House',
    icon: {
      url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange.png',
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15, 10)
    },
    label: {
      text: 'B',
      color: 'black'
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GoogleMap googlemap;

googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(new LatLng( 22.48, 114.20))
.title("My House").snippet("A").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

Comment: Hi Shahbaz, Thanks for your help. I copied the whole block of codes. The map don't show up. It seems that there is problem with the codes.

Comment: The code is right. Actually it is for android. It is my mistake that i didn't saw var in the code. And you also forgot to add html and javascript tags.

Comment: Hi Shahbaz, Thanks~~